# How to match Uri's correctly in ContentProvider?

Tags: android, uri

This is what I have, but its failing saying that the table does not exists. I am positive it does incase anyone asks that. But this is some of the code that does that:

What gets called

---

```
/*Constants*/
public static final String AUTHORITY = "content://com.smartcal.eventprovider";
private static final int EVENTS_INFO = 1;
baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(baseUri, "events_info");
    return new CursorLoader(this, baseUri, args.getStringArray("projection"), 
            args.getString("selection"), args.getStringArray("selectionArgs"), args.getBoolean("sortOrder") ? args.getString("sortOrder") : null );
```

---

What matches is

---

```
private String getTable(Uri uri) {
    String table = "";
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
    case EVENTS_INFO: table = "events_info";
    }
    return table;
}

private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static
{
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "events_info", 1);

}
```

---

And my `query()` method in custom `ContentProvider`

---

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return database.query(getTable(uri), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
}
```

Error:

---

```
06-19 17:34:14.366: E/AndroidRuntime(686): Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid tables
```

EDIT:

When using Alex's `IllegalArgumentException`, this is what I got back from the error:

```
06-19 19:17:42.277: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI
content://com.smartcal.eventprovider/events_info
```

As you can tell, it should match, assuming the `sUriMatcher.addURI()` method is working correctly.

Comment: Is it possible the table is locked?

Comment: Good point, but I do not see how it could be. Worked perfectly before, when I just had `events_info` directly in `database.query(...)`.

Comment: Ok, one more stupid question.  Have you tried using URIBuilder, rather than a raw string?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Flynn81 I am not sure how to get the stack trace. Is that like just the errors? or add code that logs it? and Pheonixblade9, not a stupid question, I haven't tried that. But the tutorials haven't shown that its necessary. But where would I use URIBuilder

Comment: How is the table being created? I would start there, verify that it is being created, per my answer.  Eliminate that as the cause of the problem first.

Comment: what does `getTable(uri)` return?

Comment: Is `EVENTS_INFO = 1`? You should be matching your uris using the static final constants in your class... not using raw integers (like `1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might stem from the fact that your code isn't very well organized...

First thing,

```
private String getTable(Uri uri) {
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case EVENTS_INFO: 
            return "events_info"; // return

        /** PROVIDE A DEFAULT CASE HERE **/
        default:
           // If the URI doesn't match any of the known patterns, throw an exception.
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
}
```

Second thing,

```
/** Use constants, not raw ints **/
sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "events_info", EVENT_INFO);
```

Other than that, you might want to provide some more info.

Comment: I will change the code up and let you know. Oh and to answer your question, yes `EVENTS_INFO` does equal 1

Comment: Btw, why did you leave return table there? Should I completely take it out? And I tried it. Still doesn't work. I don't really know what to change. Its exactly the way it should be, at least in terms of the tutorial.

Comment: Oops forgot. What does gettable return?

Comment: Returns a String my good sir. Its right there. Well to be more exact, its suppose to return a table name. I append the table to the URI when I pass it so I can dynamically change which tables it queries. But the google doc is horrible at providing detailed explanations or examples so this is what I could come up with.

Comment: Well I don't know actually. I should probably log that. Let me check

Comment: Ok so I moved the Log, and I got it showing. It doesn't return anything. I am confused why not.

Comment: Put gettable on a separate line before the query and tell me what it returns

Comment: Well the reason why it doesn't work is because it doesn't return anything :) make sure your URI matcher is working properly

Comment: I figured that, but I don't know why. My Uri matcher is exactly the way google said it should be. So I don't really know how to fix it -_- The way I have my UriMatcher formatted is all above. So tell me if you see anything thats wrong?

Comment: Make sure your URI you are passing is exactly equal to the URI you are matching it against... it most likely is not equal because otherwise it should work ok

Comment: Ok, I added an EDIT in my post. It should match as you can tell from the `IllegalArgumentException` that I get back. `AUTHORITY` obviously has the right one since its a string like like `addURI()` takes. So I don't know. I will say this. I tried `uri.getLastPathSegment()` and it works just fine. For now that works great. I could probably use another method that searchers for the `id` path as well, the `UriMatcher` is definitely causing the issue.

Comment: @Andy, post the value of every single `String` variable that is relevant to the issue you are having. And I mean every *single* one. `AUTHORITY`, `baseUri`, etc. Everything. The reason this isn't working is because of a very simple, stupid typo... it's nothing complicated. You just need to find which `String` value is incorrect and is causing your uri matcher to fail. Also post the XML in your manifest in which you register your content provider.

Comment: I cannot print everything because after you add a `Uri` into a `UriMatcher` using `addURI()` I cannot access what they are, it just returns numbers with whether is matched with the URI you provide. But you can see the structure I have above, and honestly, it's not wrong, otherwise you would have noticed the error. The Uri I send in to it is correct. What you see above is all that I added in order to match Uri's.

Comment: @Andy, there are a bunch of variables in your post that you do not tell us anything about. You could have set `AUTHORITY = "dog"` or something for all we know and that could be the error. So can you post all of the information? Otherwise we'll only be able to guess what is wrong. And the `UriMatcher` doesn't change the value of `AUTHORITY` or `baseUri` or any of those variables so I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `String` instead of `Uri` in the `UriMatcher`. I will update what you want. I added the constants in the first block of code. Let me know if any other constants are needed.

Comment: The problem is that `AUTHORITY` should be `com.smartcal.eventprovider`... it shouldn't include the scheme, `content://`. See [**here**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/) for an example. Moral of the story... post all of the information, not just the information you think is relevant :D.

Comment: Oh I how I hate and love that you are so right lmao. Thanks! So should I use that instead of `getFinalPath()` or its variant?

Comment: I've never heard of `getFinalPath()`... I've heard of `getLastPathSegment()`, if thats what you mean. Basically what you should do is look at the [**`NotePad`**](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/index.html) app and copy how they do it. It has a very well designed contract/database/provider and will teach you a lot. Read all of the comments and make sure you understand how it all works. You might also want to work through [this](http://tinyurl.com/7823k3v) tutorial and also [this](http://tinyurl.com/7d2vt2q) one too.

Comment: Oops, thats what I meant O_o Thanks for the links. Will definitely look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed the app and is the table new?  If so, and you are not updating the schema in your sql helper class, you need to uninstall the app first.  Then install the app in your emulator device.  The db is only created once, and the create method in the sql helper will not be called after that first time, even if you are installing or running a new build/apk.

Comment: Nope. Positive it gets created. Actually it should already be created. All I did was change the code. Before the code was changed that table existed. Im sure of it.